# Integrating a "watchlist" feature in php (symfony)

Tags: php, symfony1

I was looking for input about integrating a feature that:

*When a new article is added, search for users having a watchlist taht match the article categorie.
*Send them an email with the new article.

I am kind of worried it will slow the application to browse the whole watchlist table everytime a new article popup.

What would be the best way to integrate that?

Is doing a cron job that check every hours new article and compare them to watchlists a good idea? One email per day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this, I would only worry if (numberOfwatchlists) * (newArticlesPerMinute) is a very large number.

As for not spaming emails, I think a once a day check would be good.